# Getting Started with Jboss Fuse ESB

Tags: apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse

I am new to ESB and trying to understand ESB concepts and real-world use cases.

I dug into few of the open-source ESB products, seems like Apache Camel is the most famous 
one [being from Apache family].

I found out that, majority people use Jboss Fuse which developed on Apache Camel, or it's just few more added features on top of Camel.

Though, I am trying and searching the internet for almost half day and couldn't possibly find out when we use ESB and a real-world example scenario and basic tutorial to start and understand the Fuse ESB.

Could any one please point me the right direction on how to get over this and on road map, I need to integrate them with Liferay portal too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The project website for JBoss Fuse is here:

- http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse

There are links further below on that web site to the official JBoss Fuse documentation, which is currently at https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/JBoss_Fuse/ - there, you can find getting started guides and whatnot.

In the JBoss Fuse distribution, there are a number of examples in the examples directory (which will be renamed to quickstarts in the upcoming JBoss Fuse 6.1 release). These examples have readme files with instructions on how to build, deploy, and run them.

JBoss Fuse comes out of the box with Apache Camel, which is often the easiest piece to get started with, for developing integration applications. I suggest studying Camel as well. There is plenty of material on Camel at the Apache Camel website, and also some pointers on stackoverflow about how to get started with Camel, etc. And there are books as well.

Comment: @Reddy Just as a matter of interest Claus here is one of the developers of Camel.

Answer (score 1):

You be able to find JBoss Fuse getting started by using google.
For the integration of Liferay portal, I think you can check out [camel-jcr](http://camel.apache.org/jcr.html) for more information.